# Problems with URLencode in R

Tags: r, urlencode, gsub

To be able to access the NIST Chemistry Webbook database from R I need to be able to pass some query to a URL encoded web address. Most of the time this conversion works fine with URLencode(), but in some cases not. One case where it fails e.g. is for

```
query="Poligodial + 3-methoxy-4,5-methylenedioxyamphetamine (R,S) adduct, # 1"
```

which I tried to fetch using

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url=URLencode(paste0('http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=',query,'&Units=SI'))
doc=htmlParse(getURL(url),encoding="UTF-8")
```

however if you try this url in your web browser
[http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Poligodial%20+%203-methoxy-4,5-methylenedioxyamphetamine%20(R,S)%20adduct,%20%23%201&Units=SI](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Poligodial%20%20%203-methoxy-4,5-methylenedioxyamphetamine%20%28R,S%29%20adduct,%20#%201&Units=SI)
it gives name not found.
Apparently, if you try the query from
http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/name-ser.html
it is expecting the URL encoded string

```
"http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Poligodial+%2B+3-methoxy-4%2C5-methylenedioxyamphetamine+%28R%2CS%29+adduct%2C+%23+1&Units=SI"
```

Does anybody have any idea what kind of `gsub` rules I should use to arrive at the same kind of URL encoding in this case? Or is there some other easy fix?

I tried with

```
url=gsub(" ","+",gsub(",","%2C",gsub("+","%2B",URLencode(paste('http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=',query,'&Units=SI', sep="")),fixed=T),fixed=T),fixed=T)
```

but that still wasn't quite right, and I have no idea what rules the owner of the web site could have used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Richie Cotton's solution also solves for `#`, whereas `URLencode()` doesn't.

Here's a really simple example

```
# Useless...
URLencode("hi$there")
[1] "hi$there"

# This is good, but only if special characters are escaped first
URLencode("hi\\$there")
[1] "hi%5C$there"

# This works without escaping!
library(httr)
curlEscape("hi$there")
[1] "hi%24there"
```

Answer (score 5):

`URLencode` follows the [RFC1738 specification](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) (see section 2.2, page 3), which states that:

> only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

That is, it doesn't encode plusses or commas or parentheses.  So the URL it generate is correct in theory but not in practise.

The `GET` function in the `httr` package that Scott mentioned calls `curlEscape` from `RCurl`, which encodes these punctuation characters.

(`GET` calls `handle_url` which calls `modify_url` which calls `build_url` which calls `curlEscape`.)

The URL it generates is

```
paste0('http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=', curlEscape(query), '&Units=SI')
## [1] "http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Poligodial%20%2B%203%2Dmethoxy%2D4%2C5%2Dmethylenedioxyamphetamine%20%28R%2CS%29%20adduct%2C%20%23%201&Units=SI"
```

This [seems to work OK](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Poligodial%20%2b%203-methoxy-4,5-methylenedioxyamphetamine%20%28R,S%29%20adduct,%20#%201&Units=SI).

`httr` has nice features and you may want to start using it.  The minimal change to your code to get things working is simply to swap `URLencode` for `curlEscape`.

Comment: Ha many thanks - for me this is an even easier solution, especially since I prefer getURL() over GET() (it seemed a little more robust on some flaky internet connections for me)! Thx millions for this nice explanation!

Comment: A question purely out of interest/curiosity, but is does make `curlEscape()` strictly preferable to `URLencode()`? Like, in my mind, URLencode works sometimes; curlEscape works all the time..

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(httr)
url <- 'http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi'
args <- list(Name = "Poligodial + 3-methoxy-4,5-methylenedioxyamphetamine (R,S) adduct, # 1",
         Units = 'SI')
res <- GET(url, query=args)
content(res)$children$html
```

Gives

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Window-target" content="_top"/>

...etc.
```

Comment: Ha that's much better, yes - thanks a lot for this - does exactly what it should do! Thx millions!